# Can we change select tag normal scrollbars to webkit-scrollbars using CSS Property -webkit-scrollbars

Tags: html, css, webkit

How to change select tag normal scrollbars to webkit-scrollbars using CSS Property -webkit-scrollbars.

I tried with

In CSS file

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:  6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

But, it is not working for inside Select tag, Other elements like 'div',textarea' etc are working.
It will not show any scrollbars(normal) in select tag.

HTML File

```
 <select  onchange="test();" id="ViewTest" style="width: 156px; height:160px;" size="12" name="ViewStandard">
  <!-- options -->
 </select>
```

How to  get select tag the webkit-scrollbars?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I will say that *usually* styling the <select> element is not worth the trouble. It is very unreliable, especially when it comes to cross browser support. You will usually end up having to use a JavaScript library of some kind. I would be surprised if it is possible to actually use an experimental property on a <select> element.